# Is it insulting to call a full professor Dr. Firstname Lastname in a non-academic event program?

Tags: titles

I'm in charge of putting together an event program, for a non-academic (business) event. We have several academics presenting, from mainland Europe and the UK.

In the agenda is it appropriate to write, for example,

1. Topic Title - Dr. Firstname Lastname, Professor of xyz at XYZ
   University
2. Topic Title - Prof. Firstname Lastname, Professor of xyz
   at XYZ University
3. Topic Title - Prof. Dr. Firstname Lastname, Professor of xyz at XYZ University
4. Topic Title - Whatever is in their linkedin profile...

(as seems to be typical on the continent)

I ask because I would like to use appropriate titles without sounding too academic and without insulting anyone. All are full professors, one emeritus. I'd like to use the same for all if possible, for consistency.

And, I am assuming that I should use at minimum a Dr. before the name even though the job title will be listed after the name, even though speakers with MBAs etc. will not have their titles listed, and will just be Firstname Lastname... not Ms. Firstname Lastname, MBA.

Comment: It looks to me like here you are possibly using two slightly different meanings of professor together - the UK one and the US one.

Comment: The academic presenters probably care less than the people attending this event. I would use "Prof. Dr. Firstname Lastname, Department / Chair of ... XYZ University". And as you suggest I would not include an MBA. I don't think you can be too formal in the agenda. The tone during of the actual event will likely be more informal anyway.

Comment: note that in the UK academic titles may be the LEAST of your worries: http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/titles
just the widow of a marquess has 7 different styles!

Comment: I would stick to the conventions appropriate to the speakers in their home institutions. British speakers would be "Prof.", if they are full professors, Germans would be "Prof. Dr." (or "Prof. DDr.", or "Prof. Dr. Ir.", etc...whatever applies), Americans you could call just "Dr.", etc.

Comment: You could avoid honorifics and simply use 'Firstname Lastname', particularly if you have non-academics who may regard themselves as equals.

Comment: Registration forms often have 3 fields (title, firstname, lastname), or a single field where people are expected to include the title, so they can fill in whatever they like...

Comment: From my time in academia (PhD, Computer Science, UK) 'Dr' is a 'safe' term to use for academics - Professors tend not to mind their formal title being used, while non-PhDs take it as a compliment

Comment: Is it out of the question to send a timely, politely-worded email to the presenters asking them for their preferred titles?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For most people, insult and offense comes more from lack of care and respect than from mistakes.  I would thus recommend the following procedure:

1. Prepare a draft, making your best guess for each speaker based on their web presence.
2. Send out the draft agenda to all speakers, saying that this is the draft and you'd like corrections in case you have made mistakes in how anybody is listed.  (You probably want to run the schedule by them anyway for other purposes as well.)
3. Make any corrections requested by the speakers.

This way, if you get anything wrong, you're doing it in private, acknowledging possible errors, and giving them a chance to correct you in private as well.  It will be a rarely sensitive person or an unusually significant mistake that will cause offense in this way.

Comment: Note: take care to send the mails in such a way that an accidental reply-all doesn't bother the other people on the mailing list.

Comment: @Nzall If only I could bounty comments... seriously, BCC has so few legitimate and ethical uses in modern culture, but this is totally one of them!!

Comment: So are you suggesting to use different conventions for different speakers?  Not that I have been part of such an event, but I would think using the standard convention of the event's locale would make more sense.  I could imagine the end result of your suggestion ends up making those who care less about titles less distinguished.

Comment: @Kimball I would say, let the person have the title that they believe is most appropriate.  I have no need to strip a German of their extra prefix or to upgrade a British lecturer to "Prof." just because they're roughly equivalent to an Assistant Professor in the US.

Comment: I'll add that this strategy also protects you against the opposite mistake: as an accomplished researcher in an academic setting *without* a degree, I am frustrated by how often my name is listed with "Dr." or "PhD".  I think that 99% of the time, this is just laziness; the person writing has only seen researchers like me with degrees, so they assume I have one, too, instead of looking.  However, especially in situations where I'm trying to bring an applied or operational perspective to something that's suffered for being in the ivory tower too long, it begins to feel political.

Comment: @corsiKa I have created an answer to expand on this comment. It's not to hoard rep, I promise. It's so this popular remark has some more permanence, since comments may be deleted at any point.

Answer (score 14):

This strikes me as more an English usage question than an academia question.

In American English, "Doctor" is a [personal honorific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorifics), whereas "Professor" is merely the name of a job.  "Dr. Firstname Lastname" is the correct formal introduction in AmEng for anyone possessing a doctorate-level degree (PhD, MD, etc); the academic position they hold (if any) is irrelevant.  As a native speaker of this form of English, "Prof. Firstname Lastname" sounds stilted to me and "Prof. Firstname Lastname, Professor of ..." sounds redundant.

However, as pointed out in the comments, in British English, "Professor" *is* considered a personal honorific, so some of your speakers may prefer to be introduced as "Prof. Firstname Lastname".  The only way to be sure you don't irritate anyone is, as jakebeal suggests, to draft the program and then run it by everyone and ask for corrections.

In all forms of English (that I know of), honorifics are **never** stacked. "Prof. Dr." will read as a non-native speaker error.  (Multiple [postnominals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-nominal_letters) - "Dr. Snooty McSnootface, M.D., Ph.D." - are not unheard of, but they read as egotistical.  I would not put *any* postnominals on anyone's name in this context unless they themselves insisted on it.)

Comment: I concur with your second paragraph - at least in AmE. This is how I usually here it on American radio stations: "Dr. Firstname Lastname, Professor of Field at University". Sometimes it is just, "Firstname Lastname, Professor of Field at University" and then all future references are "Dr. Lastname" (assuming the person has a doctorate - if not, just "Mr. Lastname" or even just "Firstname").

Comment: The UK is rather different.  The title "Professor" (ie: *Prof. First Last*) is more prestigious than "Dr." since it indicates not only completion of a PhD, but that the individual holds a full professorship at a university.  This usually follows the career chain of postdoc -> Lecturer-> (Senior Lecturer) -> Reader -> Professor.  What you would call an "Associate Professor" in the US would be equivalent to "Senior Lecturer" in the UK; "Assistant Professor" would be a "Lecturer", etc.  The title "Professor" is reserved only for the highest tier of professorship in the UK.

Comment: @J... We have roughly the same hierarchy of faculty position prestige in the US, but none of the levels of professorship are used as  *personal honorifics* the way "Doctor" is. "Dr. (Firstname) Lastname" is correct regardless of what position he or she holds.  I guess this is another AmEng/BrEng difference.

Comment: @zwol Indeed it is such a difference.  Calling a UK Senior Lecturer a "professor" would be a mild embarassment - similar to prefixing their name with "Sir", as though they had been knighted when, in fact, they were not.  In a professional setting, introducing them as "Professor" would probably make them feel self-conscious - some would likely go so far as to correct the error: *"Professor! Would that it were... but not entirely, as it should happen.  Moving on, then..."* ;)

Comment: What you say makes sense, but, on the other hand, I have often seen the following convention beings used in North America: a speaker who holds a faculty position is listed as "Prof. First Last", while a speaker who has a doctorate but works, e.g., in a research lab, is listed as "Dr. First Last". Recent example: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/theory/s16.html

Comment: "In all forms of English (that I know of), honorifics are never stacked." But in German, they *are* stacked, and such things are considered important. Trying to abbreviate something "Herr Doktor Doktor X Y" in English may not be a good plan - and note that "Doktor Doktor" is **not** a typo.

Comment: In British English *some* honorifics are combined, whereas others are collapsed together on the basis that one improves on and replaces the other. So we don't say "Prof. Dr. Lastname", but we *would* say for example "Prof. Sir Roger Penrose" (https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/people/roger.penrose). Getting British titles and styles completely correct requires a copy of Debrett's and/or significant expertise.

Comment: ... easiest is just to ask their equerry.

Comment: @alephzero: same in Polish. One would not stack two "dr" but "prof. dr" -- yes.

Comment: Honorific _are_ stacked in the UK, but it depends on the specific honorific. For example, you could be 'Professor Sir Big Shot' but never 'Professor Dr Big Shot', and 'The Reverend Dr Priesty McPriestface'.

Comment: The general rule in British English for stacking honorifics is that you add *one* honorific of each type. "Professor" and "Doctor (Dr.)" are both academic honorifics; only use one of them. If, on the other hand, you happen to be a priest with a knighthood and a doctorate, you sit in the Commons and have been awarded a CBE... "Rev. Professor Sir John Connor, M.P., CBE"

Comment: In my field (medicine) it is normal to "stack" MD and PhD, so we can see who are clinicians and who are not. And (at least in the Netherlands) you can become a medical doctor just by finishing a bachelor's and master's. One is then officially a MSc, but on papers one usually writes MD to distinguish oneself from a non-clinician. Also would be a pity to leave out the PhD entirely.

Comment: "*In all forms of English (that I know of), honorifics are never stacked*" I know of at least one case where this is not true: In America, a pastor who holds a Doctorate is properly addressed as "*Reverend Doctor Smith*" (or "Rev. Dr. Smith" written).  And IIRC, British English stacks titles quite often.

Comment: @Jasper Those are degrees (or credentials), not honorifics.  Someone with a MSc is not addressed as *Master Jones*, but someone with a PhD or MD *is* addressed as *Doctor Smith*.  But someone with both is never addressed as *Doctor Doctor Brown*.

Answer (score 9):

I would personally omit titles in such a place at all, and just list the profession, which shows clearly that they are professors:

> Topic Title - John Doe, professor of nothing at University of Neverland.

If you do the same with everybody, you're fine: you can't insult people this way. I would say that the only people who really need a proper salutation always are Her Majesty and people of similar kind. With the others, it's just a matter of consistency.

Note that this may be field-dependent. As usually, in math and related field, people are more relaxed, in other field, this may be different.

Comment: You won't be popular in academia if you do this and in Germany it would trigger a riot if academics were separated from their Doktor title.

Comment: @TheMathemagician actually, in my experience people *outside* of academia care a lot more about a doctorate they might have. In academia few care, because it's ubiquitous anyway. In some academic circles addressing a college as Dr. can even be a bit passive-agressive, it makes a point of them being not a professor.

Comment: @quid: This really depends on the country/culture you're in. I have to support TheMathemagician: from my experience also, German academics were *very* attached to their titles.

Comment: @fgysin It also depends on the field. In my experience in Computer Science in Germany, students were on a first name and "Du" base with everyone up to doctors. Only with professors the title was used and even then, if you worked as an assistant first name wasn't unusual.
In the humanities however... Don't dare to forget saying someone's Doktor.

Comment: Most of the conferences I attended (in the field of chemistry), this was the notation in use. Peers tend to know their peers. And in Germany I made the experience that scientists don't really care about their title, at least in a collegial environment.

Comment: In case it's necessary, I suppose in this format it would be "Elizabeth Windsor, by the Grace of God of the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, and of Her other Realms and Territories Queen, Head of the Commonwealth, Defender of the Faith". Although I can't actually remember whether her surname is Windsor or Mountbatten-Windsor: her sons are Mountbatten-Windsor but I don't *think* she is.

Comment: @SteveJessop isn't that her formal style? I thought in this case the equivalent would be Queen Elizabeth II (and desperately hoping nobody mistakes her for a cruise ship)

Comment: @fgysin incidentally there is a [question about basically this now](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71078/do-german-professors-like-to-be-called-herr-x).

Comment: @Racheet: yo's listing a British professor as "John Doe, professor of nothing", that is to say "name, position" with no titles included, so I think the equivalent for the Queen is what I said, using her style to describe her position. Or it could be "EAM Windsor, Queen of the UK etc". Neither "Queen" nor "II" are parts of her name, they're respectively a title and a regnal number. However, I do agree with what yo' says, that you'd generally make an exception to the rule for monarchs even if you're listing doctors and professors without their proper titles. I would for a President too.

Comment: Obviously, what I wrote is not a "correct" way to list the Queen according to British protocol, but then what yo' wrote is not a "correct" way to list a doctor or a Professor by the same standard. There's more mileage in being a stickler for protocol around heads of state (of any nation), since if you offend a foreign academic it at least is not *automatically* a diplomatic incident.

Comment: @SteveJessop If I understand the position correctly, it would be just 'Elizabeth, by the Grace of God...': she doesn't _have_ a surname, even though her _family_ is named 'Mountbatten-Windsor'. That said, when they were in the forces, Charles's sons were deemed to have the surname 'Wales'.

Comment: @NormanGray: Yeah, well, under English common law you can go by whatever name you choose, unless for the purpose of fraud etc, even if you aren't royal. So just because a royal uses a particular surname in a particular context proves nothing about what surname they'd want to use (or a protocol officer would demand someone else uses) in any other context. Conference organisers will just have to ask them :-)

Answer (score 5):

Specifically in the UK, "Prof. Dr. Firstname Lastname" is not used. Also, "Dr. Firstname Lastname" is only appropriate if you didn't know that person was a professor.

That being said, I think there are generally two ways to list names and affiliations:

- (honorific) Firstname Lastname, Professor of xyz at XYZ University
- Prof. Firstname Lastname, Professor of xyz at XYZ University

Comment: You could probably get away with just [Professor|Dr] XY, Z University. Don't think the subject is necessary unless you're wanting it to signify context.

Comment: I'm not aware of "Prof. Dr." being used anywhere outside the German-speaking countries.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've seen it in Dutch, too (which is very close to German anyway)

Answer (score 3):

Note: This answer was originally intended as a clarification to a comment I created on jakebeal's answer that was well-received, but I ended up expanding it significantly during the writing process to the point that it can mostly stand on its own.

As jakebeal mentioned [in his answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/70995/11593), it is probably best to ask for feedback from the participants (hereafter referred to as authors) themselves so they can clarify how they want to be attributed. However, you need to ensure that communication between you and a certain author does not interfere with the other authors. In essence, this means there are several ways to go about this.

The first way is to send a mass mailing to all parties, with the addresses in BCC. This means that if one of the authors inadvertently presses "reply to all" on his mail client, his email does not reach the other authors. However, using BCC in this manner might mean that they don't reply. There are certain mail clients and mail servers that mark emails sent to a BCC mailing list as spam, and your authors might not notice it. Indeed, many companies send spam marketing mails in this way, but this isn't a marketing mail, but rather a transactional mail. You are asking for the person to take an action, not just inform them about the latest addition to your website.

In addition, such a mass mailing would have to be worded in very general terms and probably would appear obviously mass mailed. Some authors might not like that, which could have a negative effect on your relationship.

Because of this, a better alternative might be to send the emails individually. this allows you to make the email look slightly more personal and avoids most spam filters because you can put the party in the To field. It does take more time, though, so be prepared for that.

As jakebeal mentioned, a good starting point to help the authors save time clarifying their honorific and lecture is through their web presence: either their website, the website of their primary institute, or on the honor list of any award they might have won.

One final note: most academics are quite busy and some of them might not want to "waste" their time on clarifications like this. If the academic or their department has a secretary or a general administration, they might be able to help you with simple actions like their honorifics.