# Appropriate salutation for female German full professor

Tags: etiquette, professorship, germany, titles

I'm buying a desk nameplate for a full professor (in USA) who is female and of German origin. I'd like to have this nameplate follow the conventional salutation someone would use in Germany for a female at the highest academic rank.

Please note it is not important if using desk nameplates in Germany is customary or not. But if you're in Germany and have seen these in academia, I'd be interested in knowing how they're formatted. [This answer is helpful](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71078/do-german-professors-like-to-be-called-herr-x) but does not directly address how I should print this on a nameplate.

Assume the individual is called Joan A. Smith, Ph.D.

- Prof. J. A. Smith, Ph.D.
- Professor Smith
- Joan A. Smith, Ph.D. (with "professor" written underneath)
- etc?

What would be the most appropriate (German) way of engraving this item?

[image]

Comment: You mean formal German salutation in English? Name tags on doors, floor plans etc are much longer than this. Why don’t you just ask what she prefers?

Comment: In Germany, it is customary to refer to him/her as "Doctor Professor" or perhaps more accurately, "Herr Doktor Professor" if male.  I'm not sure of the female equivalent.

Comment: The abbreviated form "Prof. Dr. Joan A. Smith" is very common. Also, it is never "Doctor Professor" as @HEITZ says - the professor always comes first. An advantage of the abbreviation is that you don't have to worry about writing "Professorin" and/or "Doktorin".

Comment: @Dirk Oops, thanks for the correction. Dyslexia, I guess.

Comment: The standard format in Germany is: [Prof. Dr. FirstName LastName]. In some formal situation, they mention the type of their PhD like: [Prof. Dr.-Ing. FirstName LastName] or [Prof. Dr. rer. nat. FirstName LastName]. I think this distinction does not make sense out of Germany.

Comment: The proper answer depends on a few details which you haven't specified. Is this a (novelty) gift, or are you asked to obtain one for actual use? Has she actually obtained her PhD (and possibly higher academic degrees and/or titles) in Germany or is she simply of German extraction? (For what it's worth, I have *never* seen a nameplate in a German office, and having one would certainly raise a few eyebrows -- and not in a good way.)

Comment: If this person obtained her doctorate outside of Germany (i.e. it's an actual PhD, not a Dr.-Ing. or Dr. rer. nat.), it is illegal by German law to write "Prof. Dr. X". It has to be "Prof. X, PhD" instead. Since you're in the US it wouldn't apply, but she might care...

Comment: @nengel I like the second form you show “Prof X, PhD” and it could be something to keep and use in yhe future for her.

Comment: Having a desk nameplate is not common in Germany. A name tag on a door would normally be something like "Professor Johanna Schmidt" (i.e., only the highest academic title) or possibly in more formal places "Professor Dr. Johanna Schmidt". However, I'd find it presumptuous to put something like the latter option on my desk. So, go with the former not that formal option.

Comment: The correct title depends on.. their title. They could have one or more "Dr somethings". So it could be Prof. Dr rer. nat. Jane Doe. Or Prof. Dr. Dr. mult. Jane Doe. If you don't know stick to Professor Jane Doe (maybe Prof. Dr. Jane Doe, but if she is a honorary professor she does not necessarily have a PhD). In your case I would honestly go forth and simply ask her. If that is out of question, ask her (former) institute or secretary.

Comment: @nengel: That law has been relaxed somewhat; the title "Dr." can now be used by holders of PhDs granted in the EU and a few other countries.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_(title)#Germany.

Comment: So, you would no longer say "Frau Prof. Dr." or "Herr Prof. Dr." ??

Comment: @GEdgar That's a different question. Anyway, "Frau Prof. Dr." is *very* formal, i.e., it might be used when introducing an invited speaker or something similar. In everyday dealings I'd drop all titles, but this varies between scientific fields and regionally (e.g., I've noticed they are more formal in eastern Germany).

Comment: Unless this is a surprise, **ask her what she prefers**!

Answer (score 1):

The closest to the picture you are showing is

"Professorin Dr. Johanna Schmidt"

where the "Dr." needs to be replaced by the correct specification, e.g. Dr.-Ing., Dr. rer nat, ...

If you are having less space, you can use "Prof." instead of "Professorin" (note that "Professorin" is the female form of "Professor")

If the real title is a PhD and not a "Dr.", you should write

"Professorin Johanna Schmidt, PhD"

In all cases, the first name might be abbreviated. In Germany it is relatively uncommon to use the second name - you should check how she uses it and follow the style she prefers.

I would not write "Professorin" underneath the name - it looks strange to me.